# function with input check and retry option

Tags: c, function, pass-by-reference

I want to know how I can implement an input check in the function getFloats so that if the user enters an undesired input (e.g a word or letter instead of a number) that the function prints a message and gives the user the option to try again and this function exits and won't give an option to retry an input. Is it more professional to stop using scanf and start using a better input method ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getFloats(float *a, float *b);

int main()
{
    float num1,num2;
    
    getFloats(&num1,&num2);
    printf("%.2f and %.2f\n", num1, num2);
    
    return 0;
}

void getFloats(float *a, float *b)
{
    puts("Enter numbers:");
    scanf("%f", a);
    if ( scanf("%f", a) == 0)
    {
        puts("try again");
        scanf("%f", a);
    }
    else
    {
        scanf("%f", b);
    }
}
```

Comment: I never use `scanf()`. I prefer to read the whole line and then use the `strtol()` and `strtof()` family of functions.

Comment: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: The page in the comment of my link above also explains when it is appropriate to use `scanf` and when `fgets` is better.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel That article was an incredible suggestion. thank you

Answer (score 1):

regarding;

```
scanf("%f", a);
if ( scanf("%f", a) == 0)
```

1. this is calling `scanf()` twice for the same variable
2. best to check for a positive condition.

Here is a suggested code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
...

void getFloats(float *a, float *b)
{
    puts("Enter numbers:");

    if( scanf( "%f %f", a, b ) != 2 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
```

It is VERY unlikely that calling `scanf()` repeatedly will fix the problem because the problem will still be in the `stdin` stream